# sharepoint installation windows 7 64 bit

Tags: sharepoint

i want to know that on which windows 7 64 version ms share point 2010 server can be installed . i installed it on ultimate but it is not supporting it. it is saying to install windows server 2008. i heard from the video that share point 2010 can be installed on 64 bit windows 7

Comment: It is also possible to install MOSS (SharePoint 2007) on Windows 7. Not 2003 though. :( Note you need 64-bit everything to run SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are instructions from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx

Comment: We found the instructions unintuitive, be sure to install the relavent patches to different products, eg. WCF hotfix, ASP .Net hotfix.